# PreparedStatement lanza error al intentar pasar un nombre de tabla como parámetro

Tags: java, prepared-statements

Recién comienzo con java. Alguien puede decirme por qué este código da error en la consulta SQL al tratar de usar `PreparedStatement`

```java
PreparedStatement myStatement = c1.prepareStatement("Select * from ?");
```

Comment: SJuan76 sin duda genero confusión mi comentario. Ya lo elimine. No preste atención al detalle que estaba refiriendo al nombre de la tabla. Ya que al setear el valor daria como resultado ''tablax'' y eso generaria un error de sentencia SQL. Gracias por tu observación.

Comment: Siempre es necesario añadir el error que sale

Answer (score 1):

Puedes revisar la sintaxis de la sentencia SQL, cuando trabajas con `statements`, es de ayuda ademas el stackTrace lanzado por java:

```sql
Select * from <TABLE_NAME>
```

`<TABLE_NAME>` teniendo algún valor como `usuarios` tu código java debería ser:

```
PreparedStatement myStatement = c1.prepareStatement("Select * from usuarios");
```

ya cuando tengas el `where` debes de usar los parámetros usando `?`

Answer (score 1):

Los placeholders '?' solo se aplican a parámetros, no a tablas ni a columnas.
Si quieres agregar tablas dinámicamente, tendrás que hacerlo en el propio String.
Documentación en inglés: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html